# change C# object to type decided at run-time

Tags: c#, winforms, type-conversion

#### The problem

I have a WinForms program that has to talk to different pieces of hardware using different connection types such as TCP, USB, etc. Using the connections entails using a common set of actions provided by VISA (such as open, read, write, close). How data is passed to these functions or any transforms that might need to be applied to the data before or after use would vary by connection type.

The connections are used to connect to different pieces of hardware when some method decides that a particular hardware operation requires a type of certain connection (specified by some other data).

At some point in the future I might like to add more types of connections.

A user of the application can select and edit a connection part of which entails changing the connection type (i.e. change from using TCP to using USB). Changing the type means different method implementations will be used to operate the physical connection. It is this change of type when editing a connection that I am working on.

The data related to each connection (including type data) is persisted via an external data source.

#### My solution so far

I have an abstract class `Connection` with some derived types such as `Tcp`, `Usb`, etc, they have common methods and properties from the abstract class (e.g. `Address`, `Open()`, etc) but the implementations differ to get the different data and address formats in the correct format for the VISA interface.

The application starts by populating a `List<Connection>` from the source of data. On this List are objects of the types derived from `Connection`.

To present the user with controls to allow the changing of type when one of the connections from the list is selected but still keep the usage generalised the form has `RadioButton` controls that are created by a method that uses reflection to find generate one object of each of the derived classes and adds the names of them to the form, *with a common `CheckedChanged` event handler*.

For example:

```
ConnectionIEnumerable = GetObjectsDerivedFromType<Connection>();
foreach (Connection c in ConnectionIEnumerable)
{
     var rb = new RadioButton();
     rb.Name = c.ToString() + "RadioButton";
     rb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CommonEventHandler);
     form1.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(rb);
}
```

#### Where I'm stuck

How can this generic handler that is used "know" what type to convert the currently selected object to? How does the RadioButton store and impart the information about a related type that should be converted to?

I've looked at trying this plan other ways but it always comes back to a requirement that at some point there would need to be some kind of `if` checking the current type to convert it, or checking the type to be converted to, thus introducing non-generality.

I think the OOP encapsulation way of doing this would be to *somehow* associate type information with each `RadioButton` as it's created and have the types themselves define how to convert between them but I'm not sure if this is correct, or of the best way of doing this; use cast overrides, a type converter, `IConvertible`, etc. Such that the handler could use something like (for example only) the below, to replace the object on the List:

```
    currentObject.ConvertTo( (Type)( (RadioButton)sender).Tag ) );
```

#### Update:

For anyone with a similar quandary I took Patrick Hoffman's answer and saved type information to the `RadioButton.Tag` like so:

```
rb.Tag = c.GetType()
```

Then used it in the handler like:

```
EditedConnection = (Connection)Activator.CreateInstance((Type)((RadioButton)sender).Tag);
```

Comment: Where do you set `sender.Tag`? You shouldn't need to convert anything since the instance will already have the correct dynamic type. You might need to cast to some more specific static type e.g. `Connection`.

Comment: @Lee, I dont set it, that line is just an example of the *kind* of operation I _think_ I'm aiming for, something where the RadioButton can impart some information about the type relatd to it.

Comment: What is the object you're trying to convert? An instance of `Connection`? Can you cast to the base class or do you need to cast to each specific subclass? How is the initial `List<Connection>` populated?

Comment: @Lee the initial `List<Connection>` is populated from an external data source (a JSON file). The base class does not have the information neccessary to actually use a particular type of connection - a TCP type connection must use a physical TCP connection, it's implementation will be different to one that uses a USB connection - this is why I _think_ I need to change type. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Lee, it's trying to convert an instance of , say `Tcp` which is contained on the `List<Connection>`

Comment: It sounds like you want a `Dictionary<Type, Action<Connection>>` where each delegate casts to some known subtype in the handler. Then in your form you can do `var handler = dict[sender.Tag.GetType())]; handler((Connection)sender.Tag)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can this generic handler that is used "know" what type to convert the currently selected object to?

It shouldn't need to know that. If your program solely depends on the abstract base class, the only think you need to do is instantiate the type once, and use the base class throughout your program.

If you need to construct an instance, [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you need. You could retrieve the type from the reflection you did before to populate the list.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand - the code can refer only to the base class in most cases, but ultimately the user is selecting a change from one type to another that means a change in the implementation that is referred to has to be enacted at some point, right?

Comment: Okay, so assign a new instance to whatever you need, maybe in some generic class that holds the current instance.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing what you mean, but where you say "assign a new instance", of which type? Say the user has selected "USB", how does the handler know to create a `Usb` instance?

Comment: You said you fill the list walking the types from reflection. When you know that type, you can call `Activator.CreateInstance` with it. Assign the outcome to your variable.

Comment: No I fill the RadioButton controls from reflection of walking the types (edited to make that clearer), the result being one `Usb` object, one `Tcp` object, etc. This is not related to the list of connections currently in use. I can keep this list too but I don't know how to relate one of these objects to the relevant RadioButton... that's what Im asking?

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Can you show more code? Specifically how you retrieve the types and fill the list?

Comment: I took your activator suggestion and it's worked! Thank you! (I saved the objects Type to the RadioButton.Tag property like I thought then used similar to my idea at the end of my question).